# How to select the last 12 months in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I need to select the last 12 months. As you can see on the picture, May occurs two times.
But I only want it to occur once. And it needs to be the newest one.
Plus, the table should stay in this structure, with the latest month on the bottom.

[image]

And this is the query:

```
SELECT Monat2,
       Monat,
       CASE WHEN NPLAY_IND = '4P'
               THEN 'QuadruplePlay'
            WHEN NPLAY_IND = '3P'
               THEN 'TriplePlay'
            WHEN NPLAY_IND = '2P'
               THEN 'DoublePlay'
            WHEN NPLAY_IND = '1P'
               THEN 'SinglePlay'
       END AS Series,
       Anzahl as Cnt
FROM T_Play_n
where NPLAY_IND != '0P'
order by Series asc ,Monat
```

This is the new query

```
SELECT sub.Monat2,sub.Monat,
CASE WHEN NPLAY_IND = '4P'
    THEN 'QuadruplePlay'
     WHEN NPLAY_IND = '3P'
    THEN 'TriplePlay'
     WHEN NPLAY_IND = '2P'
    THEN 'DoublePlay'
    WHEN NPLAY_IND = '1P'
    THEN 'SinglePlay'
END
AS Series, Anzahl as Cnt FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY Monat2 ORDER BY Monat DESC)rn, 
                 Monat2,
                 Monat,
                 Anzahl,
                 NPLAY_IND
            FROM T_Play_n)sub
 where sub.rn = 1
```

It does only show the months once but it doesn't do that for every Series.
So with every Play it should have 12 months.

[image]

Comment: what about a 'distinct' or a 'group by'

Comment: your current query would help

Comment: Which rdbms do you use?

Comment: Why do you store month twice? (As May, and 05 part of column 2.)

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I am using SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Oracle` and `SQL-Server` you can use `ROW_NUMBER`.

`name` = month name and `num` = month number:

```
  SELECT sub.name, sub.num
    FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY num DESC) rn,
                 name,
                 num
            FROM tab) sub
   WHERE sub.rn = 1
ORDER BY num DESC;
```

Comment: How can I do it in SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: @fusionchart_help, in sql server it is exactly the same

Comment: @Giorgi Nakeuri, Thanks. It works without in my IDE, but you are right.

Comment: @JonTofte-Hansen I tried it like that but it doesn't really work--> I updated my post with the new query

Comment: @fusionchar_help, it looks like you need to include all your fields from T_Play_n in the subquery.

Comment: @JonTofte-Hansen So this query does something similar like i wanted. But inside the Series there are 1P, 2P, 3P,4P and to every Series, it should have 12 months, so in total it should be 48

Comment: @fusionchart_help, put all the relevant "header" values in the partition by: partition by NPlay_IND, Monat2

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH R(N) AS
(
    SELECT 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT N+1 
    FROM R
    WHERE N < 12
)

SELECT LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,-N,GETDATE())),3) AS [month]
FROM R
```

The `With R(N)` is a Common Table Expression.The R is the name of the result set (or table) that you are generating. And the N is the month number.

Answer (score 0):

In `SQL Server` you can do It in following:

```
SELECT DateMonth, DateWithMonth -- Specify columns to select
FROM Tbl -- Source table
WHERE CAST(CAST(DateWithMonth AS INT) * 100 + 1 AS VARCHAR(20)) >= DATEADD(MONTH, -12,GETDATE()) -- Condition to return data for last 12 months
GROUP BY DateMonth, DateWithMonth -- Uniqueness
ORDER BY DateWithMonth -- Sorting to get latest records on the bottom
```

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like you want to select rows that contain the last occurrence of months. Something like this should work:

```
select * from [table_name]
where id in (select max(id) from [table_name] group by [month_column])
```

The last select in the brackets will get a list of id's for the last occurrence of each month. If the year+month column you have shown is not in descending order already, you might want to max this column instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this(the table dbo.Nums contains int values from 0 to 11)

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19991201', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) + n - 12, '19991201'),
       DATENAME(MONTH,DateAdd(Month, DATEDIFF(month, '19991201', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) + n - 12, '19991201'))
FROM dbo.Nums
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a `group by` for the month name, and a `max` function for the numeric component. If is not numeric, use `to_number()`.